# Can I say "thousands of <something>" to make it sound more dramatic when it's actually "a thousand and a half"?

Tags: business-language

I'm writing a letter to my friends and I want to make some parts of it sound more impressive and say in one part of the letter

```
"thousands of <something>"
```

Can I say so if  is actually in order of 1,500?

From English language perspective, can I say "thousands of < items > (something)" when it's just "1,500"?

For example,

"thousands of dollars" when I mean 1,500 dollars.

Or

"thousands of nails" when I mean 1,500 nails.

Comment: Outside of the general freedom to say whatever you want, so long as you don't care what other people think, ***no***. What you *can* say is "*I've got a five-figure income!*", which could mean anything from $10,000/year to $99,999/year  (all numbers in that range have *five digits*), but most people assume when you're saying it in a *confident*, *proud* way, you mean the *high* end.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to lie but I want to make it more impressive. Would I be able to say "thousands of dollars" if it was 1) 1,999, 2) 2,000, 3) 2,001?

Comment: Just some general advice --not language related: Don't do this unless you want to receive back "thousands" of requests for loans!

Comment: Boasting about something that is clearly false is never wise. Thousands of dollars, I would automatically assume is anything over $2,000.

Comment: There is a very much on-topic question somewhere in here, but clearly not in the current wording. You *can* say anything you want. And by the way: if you wanted to make it sound more impressive, you should say you are making billions a day. Thousands a month is not impressive at all. I am being paid a trillion just for copy-pasting this comment from my ghostwriter, who *actually* gets paid thousands of dollars a month, and you are the first person I learn of that earns less than him.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more general. Sorry.

Comment: This reminds me of the unit of measure: the Sagan, which means "billions and billions", or 4 billion.  The reasoning is that 'billions' is plural so you have at least 2.  So the minimum you could have if you say "billions and billions" is 4 billion.

Comment: Note: if you said there were ‘thousands’ of something, and it turns out there are in fact only 2,007 of them, I would in general be just as disappointed and underwhelmed as if there turned out to be only 1,838 of them, even if it is mathematically sound enough. Depending on the thing being counted (and whether it’s hyperbole), ‘thousands of’ hints at different magnitudes; but to use it for anything less than at least around 3–4,000 is likely to cause underwhelmment in quite a few cases. If you say you earn ‘thousands of dollars’ per week, I’d probably assume at least 5–6,000.

Answer (score 2):

First, we come to the question of whether this is a question about English language usage or a request for personal advice.  I'll say the following in the spirit of the latter.

Yes, you CAN say that.  Whether you should say it that way is another question.

Two points:

- Mathematically, 1,500 to the nearest thousand rounds to 2,000.  So, in a certain sense use of the plural is perhaps permissible, even if possibly misleading.
- On the other hand, every dollar over 1,000 is a dollar of the second thousand.  As is pointed out in comments, when we speak of unitary quantities with fractional components we always use the plural. E.g. 1 gallon, but 1.5 gallons. 1 mile, but 1.2 miles.  And going the other way, what would we do about something less than a unitary quantity?  1 mile, and .7 mile - both singular.

The other question, of course, is whether you'd be embarrassed to have your friends expect you make at least $2,000 only to find that you're actually making $500 short of that figure.

In your place, I would feel more comfy in telling my friends that I make well over a thousand dollars.

Your mileage may differ, of course.

Comment: Does the "On the other hand, every dollar over 1,000 is a dollar of the second thousand" analysis help explain why it's "1.25 acreS of land"? (+1, btw)

Comment: Actually, yes.  This happens in the reporting of the size of many units in English.  Same thing with 1 1/2 gallonS.

Comment: For 0.7, I think most people would say "0.7 miles", not "0.7 mile".

Comment: +1 for "well over $1,000".  If I was going to do the bragging, I'd go with that option! :-)

Comment: @pacoverflow, yes, perhaps.  I wouldn't, but I am sure I've heard other people say it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to make it more general. Other examples include 1500 nails.

Answer (score 1):

One thousand five hundred isn't a plurality of the thousands so no, it doesn't make sense to say thousands. But it's not like they're ever going to see your paycheck, right?

Comment: Yes right, they're not gonna see my pay check.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more general.